# Showing family is NOT complete

Tags: statistics

How would I show that $$f(x;\theta) = \frac1{2\theta}$$ where $x$ is between positive and negative $\theta$ and $\theta$ is between $0$ and $\infty$ is NOT a complete family?

I know that I need to find a non-zero function $u(x)$ whose expectation will be $0$, but I am struggling with finding this function.

Thanks

Comment: Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution is known to be one of these. Then by symmetry $E(X)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* try a function $u(x)$ which is odd, i.e., with $$u(-x) = -u(x).$$

Comment: If I select $U(x)=x^3$this works right?

Comment: Then the integration=0 but it does not require u(x) to be zero right?

Comment: @clarkson: all the expansion coefficients are 0 but the function is not zero so the family is not complete.